# Views, Panels, Block not translating

Tags: views, blocks, panels, i18n-l10n

In a panel, I'm trying to add a view block and I'm trying to translate my views title  l but it's not displaying anything or translating. Below you can see my settings in my panels.
[image]

If I dont override the title, it's still blank. I dont see the English or the FR translations.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought there was already support for translatable pane titles in Panels with the i18n_panels submodule. However, looking at [Issue #117934](https://www.drupal.org/node/1179034) which is currently marked fixed, there are still people providing patches. Though that issue title states it is for translatable Panel PAGE titles, the patch on [comment #106](https://www.drupal.org/node/1179034#comment-9797715) actually modifies code to make pane titles translatable.

Note that from an architectural perspective the approach in comment #106 is frowned upon because you are not supposed to pass dynamic text through t().  I would consider this a small permissible hack to get you across the finish line without wasting too much time.